# @Transactional not applied to all controller actions

Tags: grails, transactions, spring-transactions, grails3

We notices after the update from Grails 3.1.11 to 3.2.0 that one action of a controller is no longer working:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class RoomPlanController {
    ...
    def show(RoomPlan roomPlan) {
        ...
    }
    def getRooms(RoomPlan roomPlan) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that when we call `roomPlan/getRooms/1` `roomPlan` is null. If we call the `show` action with the same parameter roomPlan is set correct.

A call of `getErrors()` inside the controller gives us the following error message:

> Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

which has it's origin from grails.artefact.Controller.initializeCommandObject. After some more debugging I noticed a difference in the stacktrace between `show` and `getRooms`

Stacktrace of `show`:

```
show:100, RoomPlanController (at.byte_code.businessSuite.hotel)
$tt__show:-1, RoomPlanController (at.byte_code.businessSuite.hotel)
doCall:-1, RoomPlanController$_show_closure13 (at.byte_code.businessSuite.hotel)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
```

Stacktrace of `getRooms`:

```
getRooms:109, RoomPlanController (at.byte_code.businessSuite.hotel)
getRooms:-1, RoomPlanController (at.byte_code.businessSuite.hotel)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (sun.reflect)
```

The error message and the different stacktrace let us assume it has something to do with the database session/transaction and after adding `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` to the action everything work as expected and before the update to grails 3.2.0. If we remove the annotation and fails again.

We were not able see the issue in any other controller and were not able to reproduce it in a small test project. We already tried to rebuild the project, also on a completely new workstation we were not.

Did anybody else observed such an issue?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, (lots of people doing service work in a controller). shouldn't transactional be used in the context of services ? Not saying what you have raised isn't a valid question. Just purely around best approach and correct usage

Comment: You're correct, but the controllers generated by Grails include annotations. I assume this is because there's no script currently that will autogenerate a corresponding service, only an empty one, so the logic must have been that it's better to have the correct transaction demarcation (the save/update/delete actions have @Transactional and the rest have @Transactional(readonly=true)) in the wrong place than none at all.

Comment: the action only render some data of the model, so IMHO a seperate service is unnecessary and overhead. Maybe I'm wrong but this is the way that is sugested way from the generated grails controllers as Burt Beckwith pointed out.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "suggested" at all. It's simply that way. The "suggested" and "proper" way is in fact to use a service. The overhead of having and using a service is so small compared the overall application it's laughable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would even need @Transactional(readOnly = true) in controller.

Grails controllers are by default readOnly. You can simply delete the annotation from the controller.

In contrast, Grails service class are transactional by default. If you need to call the save() method, it's more desirable to call that method in the service class.

Comment: Without @Transactional the databinding of domain classes is not working, because controllers by default are not transactional. The question is if anybody else observed the issue that the class level transactional annotation is not applied to all actions

Comment: I don't think @Transactional has anything to do with databinding with properties of domain classes. When I have applied class level transactional annotation, it has applied to all actions. Check your UrlMapping rules to make sure the rule applicable to show() was also applicable to getRooms()

Comment: well THIS is the actual issue that the class level annotation is not applied. works in grails 3.1.x, fails in 3.2. At least for this controller. We cannot observe or reproduce the error in other controllers. Because we cannot reproduce the issue in a test project we can't create a issue ticket in the grails projekt and we ask here if anybody observe the same issue to find it's root cause.